# How to add Script tag by inLine Script in Thymeleaf?

Tags: javascript, html, spring, thymeleaf, template-engine

I have written following code into Thymeleaf template to load jQuery from server if cdn link fail.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"><\/script>');
</script>
```

Thymeleaf is interpreting `document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>')` as script tag which should imterpret as a string.

I'm getting following error near `<\/script>` tag.

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of elements must consist of
>   well-formed character data or markup.

Any solution or work around for this problem?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your scripts in CDATA blocks for this:

```
<script>
    // <![CDATA[
    window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"><\/script>');
    // ]]>
</script>
```